# INNER JOIN with distinct columns

Tags: sql, oracle18c

I'm able to code a select statement that performs my query.  However, I'm looking for the "DepartmentID" column displayed to only show unique values.

I'm attempting to use both "UNIQUE" and "DISTINCT" in various places but I'm unsuccessful.  Here is the sample table data:

Output shows all "DepartmentID" entries, but I only want entries with unique values to be displayed.

Comment: Did you already try `SELECT DISTINCT`?  If that didn't meet your needs, then can you add data showing what the problem is?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Marcus uses `UNIQUE` which is a synonym for `DISTINCT`

Comment: And if a department has multiple employees, how should that be displayed?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "unique" values, you mean departments with exactly one employee, then use aggregation:

```
SELECT d.departmentid, d.departmentname, 
       MAX(e.FirstName || ' ' || e.LastName) AS Chair
FROM Employees e JOIN
     Departments d
     ON e.departmentid = d.departmentid 
GROUP BY d.departmentid, d.departmentname
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
ORDER BY d.departmentid;
```

EDIT:

Based on your updated question, you don't need aggregation at all.  Just the correct `JOIN` conditions:

```
SELECT d.departmentid, d.departmentname, 
       (e.FirstName || ' ' || e.LastName) AS Chair
FROM Employees e JOIN
     Departments d
     ON e.employeeid = d.departmentchair 
ORDER BY d.departmentid;
```

Comment: I don't believe this will work.  Please see my newly added source material which includes the table information as well as my desired outcome.  My current SELECT statement returns all entries found in the Employees Table, but I only want the unique values (1, 2, 3) returned, so a total of 3 values returned.